# How to use the output variable of external script from SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

```
execute sp_execute_external_script
@language=N'Python'
@script=N'import pandas as pd
 for i in range(len(data.columns)-4):
    needed_cols=data.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,i+4]]
    needed_cols.columns=target_table.columns
    target_table=target_table.append(needed_cols)
 output_table=target_table'
@input_data_1=N'Select col1, col2, col3 from dummy_table'
@input_data_1_name=N'data'
@output_data_1_name=N'output_table'
```

Consider the above mentioned example I wish to use the final output_table variable to insert values in a real SQL table in the same database, how should I approach this?

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with? The data goes into `output_table`, does that not work?

Comment: I am unable to use the output_table, typical select statement doesn't work with it

Comment: I think the idea is you do `CREATE TABLE output_table` first

Comment: You should first create the table, then insert as follows:
`INSERT INTO output_table
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
...`